# Unable to access response.status with React from a custom rails API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the status of a request I do from a React website I am working on, using axios to fetch make requests to a RoR API I developed. I would like to confirm that the POST request succeeded by accessing the status value from this (which is the output of a `console.log(response)`:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }​
<state>: "fulfilled"​
<value>: Object { data: {…}, status: 201, statusText: "Created", … }​​
config: Object { url: "pathname", method: "post", data: "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"lou10@email.com\",\"username\":\"lou10\",\"password\":\"azerty\"}}", … }​​
data: Object { data: {…} }​​
headers: Object { "cache-control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }​​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
status: 201
statusText: "Created"​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
index.jsx:51:11
```

But when I try a `console.log(response.status)` all I get is an `undefined`.

Here is the code :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from "./config.js";

const post = async (
  endpoint,
  body = null,
  jwt_token = null,
  header = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }) => {

  let opt = header;
  if (jwt_token){
      opt["Authorization"] = jwt_token
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(BASE_URL + endpoint, body, { headers: opt })
    return response
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`An error occurred while trying to fetch ${endpoint}. ${err}`);

  }
}

export default post;
```

```
const handleSignup = async ({ email, username, pwd }) => {
    let body = {
        user: {
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: pwd
        }
    };
    return await post("/users", body);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (passwordCheck === false) {
        console.log("Passwords do not match");
    } else if (passwordCheck === true && userData) {
        const response = await handleSignup(userData);
        console.log(response.status);
        // history.push({ pathname: "/", state: response.status });
    }
}, [passwordCheck, userData]);
```

I am thinking to change the response from my API, but I really doubt it is the right approach.

Edit 1: adding some complementary code

Comment: can you share your axios code

Comment: Is the promise you pasted above the result of `handleSignup`? Either way, `handleSignup` is most likely async thus you'll need to wait for the promise to resolve

Comment: It's a Promise, you need to await it : `const response = await handleSignup(userData);`

Comment: @Mohindersingh : I added the axios code.

@Tom : Yes the promise I pasted above is the result of `handleSignup(userData)`. Indeed it is an aync arrow function, but I don't know why, I cannot "await it", it triggers an error `Unexpected reserved word 'await'.`

@JeremyThille : I already tried that, and it actually triggers an error `Unexpected reserved word 'await'.`.

Comment: for await keyword error, I think you are missing async in useEffect

Comment: @Mohindersingh : thanks, that was it, problem solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare the function you give in parameter to `useEffect` as `async` to be able to use `await` inside for your async function `handleSignup`

```
 useEffect(async () => {
if (passwordCheck === false) {
    console.log("Passwords do not match");
} else if (passwordCheck === true && userData) {
    const response = await handleSignup(userData);
    console.log(response.status);
    // history.push({ pathname: "/", state: response.status });
}
}, [passwordCheck, userData]);
```

Comment: That's what I did, as @Mohindersingh proposed in the comment of my post. But thantks to you !

Comment: Ah yeah didn't see that! since he didn't post an answer could you choose this as accepted so that it can help someone else that might have the same problem in the future